# Windows 7 Blue Screen Error while trying to share internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, bsod

### Problem Description

My PC functions normally in all respects, but as soon as I try to share my broadband connection by using some app like [mhotspot](http://mhotspot.com/), or [my Wifi Router](https://filehippo.com/download_my_wifi_router/), as soon as another computer connects to the network, I get a blue screen error, saying **DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_RQUAL**, with an error code **0x00000001**, pointing to **rtl8192c3.sys**.

Do note that, I've been using these virtual router apps for quite some time, and they never gave any major issue. Once I tried to connect another device to the broadband, and had to reset the network switch in the proces, after which these errors started coming up.

Please find below a piture of the blue screen.
A couple of the dump files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HrgpZhS6RLaOJJbhuYQVvKNwvuLzIlsc?usp=sharing)

[image: Picture of the sample blue screen]

### What I've done till now

- Deleted the netork drivers and did scan for new hardware to get fresh driver installations.
- Based on some online forum suggestion, replaced the **rtl8192c3.sys** file with a fresh copy.
- Some other random fixes like `flushdns` etc.

### System Informtion

- Windows 7 Utimate 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
- System model: Lenovo C320

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The driver `rtl8192Ce.sys` is pointing to a bad virtual address (uninitialized garbage or freed memory) which is causing the crash.

I'd recommend the following:

1. Uninstall NDIS Driver from Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (you have old one installed on Thu Sep 9, **2010**).
2. Install latest one (year **2013**) from here: [Realtek NDIS Driver](https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/NETWORK-CARD/REALTEK/Realtek-RTL8192CE-VA4-WLAN-Adapter-Driver-20071204192013.shtml).
3. I would also update BIOS, low level chipset drivers to the latest version.
4. For more help, please refer this link: [Microsoft support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/irqlnotlessorequal-error/af4c4487-3f13-4055-9f35-b3de401bcbcf).

Thanks.